# Should I edit a question to address a new concern or create a new one?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

Say, there is ["maxim" vs "aphorism" question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17375/whats-the-difference-between-an-aphorism-and-a-maxim). I want to know the difference between "tenet" and "maxim". Do I edit the first question, extending it with the new concern, or create a new one?

Comment: A question about **tenet** is at most "related" to the linked question about **maxim** vs **aphorism**. Besides, tenets are more about *beliefs*, whereas maxims and aphorisms are often just *sayings*, which you may or may not believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have answered yourself: a new *concern* is a new *question.* One important consideration is that adding a new concern would invalidate, in part, every answer which has already been posted.

You should edit

> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> [from [edit questions and answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)]

but should not edit to change the meaning of the post.